# Hundrednths appearance in a double variable in java

Tags: java, double

I am using [Sparrow's Kmax](http://www.sparrowcorp.com/products/software) framework and I have those two methods

```
public void setValueTo(String widgName, double val) {
        String str = Double.toString(val);
        KmaxWidget widg = tlsh.getKmaxWidget(widgName);
        widg.setProperty("TEXT", str);
} // setValueTo

public void ROI(KmaxWidget widget){

        setValueTo("SUM", hist1D.getRegionSum(null));
        setValueTo("CENTROID", hist1D.getRegionCentroid(null)[0]);
        setValueTo("FWHM", hist1D.getRegionFWHM(null)[0]);
}//ROI
```

The first one has two arguments, one of them being `double`. The second method, is linked to GUI's objects, so `SUM`, `CENRTROID` and `FWHM` are actually text fields. The values that appear in those text fields have many numbers after the decimal point. Is there a way to "remove" those many numbers without having to change the type of variable?

Note that I cannot use print commands(due to the framework I am working).

Comment: java.text.DecimalFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a `String` using [format specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) (`%.3f`) to indicate how many numbers after the decimal point will be showed:

```
double number = 10.123124123;
String str = String.format("%.3f", number); // 3 decimals

System.out.println(str); // 10,123
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The problem is that the value that is printed, comes from an object. The important thing is that I cannot use `print` commands. I can only use methods. For instance a method that converts double to sth(without including print commands) could be the key, but I don't know how to do it without print commands.

Comment: The second line of the code above, would replace your line `String str = ...`. The print statement I put, is just to show the result, you can ommit it.